# Printing hollow shell with concave recess ("fill plug") -- Cura automatically fills in "fill plug"

Tags: ultimaker-cura, troubleshooting, 3d-models

I am trying to print a hollow shell from a mesh I generated in Blender.

The model itself has zero-thickness and I am using Cura "walls" option to create the print. However. The model is designed to be filled with sand for weight and then have a plastic plug secured in the bottom to retain the sand once filled. I simply use a drill to create the "penetration" into the hollow model once the print is complete since Cura finds printing a shell with non-manifold geometry to be illegal.

The concave recess is on the bottom of the model, to allow for the thickness of the rubber plug and still sit flush on the table. Unfortunately it seems this concave cavity I designed is removed in Cura automatically. I have been unsuccessful in figuring out how to get this recessed area to print.

Shown below are slightly different models. I tried importing the mesh into Fusion to "add wall thickness" to the cylindrical recess but it was still removed automatically by Cura as an un-printable overhang/hole?

[image]
[image]
[image]